# Wicket IDataProvider & LoadableDetachableModel

Tags: wicket

I've a question regarding the IDataProvider and the model method. The wicket guide says that you can wrap the item in a detacheable model to prevent them from beeing serialized. If I wrap the model object directly in a loadabledetacheablemodel it is still serialized. It will not detached. If I get only the Id and retrieve it again (e.g. from the databse) each item will retrieved again which already loaded in the load method. Makes the usage of the LDM in an DataProvider any sense? Is there a way to detach all objects with only one query to the databse in the load method?

I've seen some other posts here regarding this problem but none of them satisfied me...

Thanks!

Comment: Ah I may found the problem by myself in all example I've seen the parameter in the model object is marked as final and used in the load method of the LDM. But I think I shoud use the object as a parameter in the LDM constructor?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ContactDataProvider/DetachableContactModel in wicket-examples.